# Java: Casting one subclass to another?

Tags: java

I'm attempting to understand something I read in a research paper that suggested that you can improve performance with shared objects in Java by making use of the RTTI facilities.  The main idea is that you have a class with two empty subclasses to indicate the status of an implicit "bit" in the main class.  The reference I'm looking at is in the paper here: http://cs.brown.edu/~mph/HellerHLMSS05/2005-OPODIS-Lazy.pdf in Section 3: Performance.

I am attempting to replicate this technique with a data structure that I'm working on.  Basically I have:

```
class Node {
...
}

class ValidNode extends Node {}
class DeletedNode extends Node {}
```

I then create an object with:

```
Node item = new ValidNode();
```

I want to somehow cast my instance of `ValidNode` to an instance of `DeletedNode`.  I've tried the following:

```
Node dnode = DeletedNode.class.cast( node );
```

and

```
Node dnode = (DeletedNode)node;
```

However, both terminate with a ClassCastException.  I have to assume that what I am attempting to do is a valid technique, since the author (who in turn integrated this technique into the Java1.6 library) clearly knows what he's doing.  However, I don't seem to have enough Java guru-ness to figure out what I'm missing here.

I intend to use something along the lines of

```
if ( node instanceof DeletedNode ) { // do stuff here
```

Thank you all in advance.

=============
EDIT:

It looks like the following might work:

```
class Node {
    ...
}

class ValidNode extends Node {}
```

I then create (un-deleted) nodes as of type `ValidNode`.  When I wish to mark a node as deleted, I then cast the node up the chain to type `Node`.  I can then test if a node has been deleted with `if (!(node instanceof ValidNode))`.

I'll give this a try.

Comment: RTTI in Java is called "reflection".

Comment: The author probably knows what he's doing, but you probably didn't understand what he did correctly. Casting an apple to a banana doesn't make sense. An apple is an apple, and can't become a banana by casting. Casting a fruit to apple makes sense, and will only work if the fruit indeed is an apple.

Comment: I don't see anything about casting between subclasses anywhere in that paper. Remember the I in RTTI stands for *inference* (or identification), you don't do anything to the type, only try to determine what it is.

Comment: I am looking towards the bottom of Page 11, where the author refers to the "LockFreeRTTI" algorithm, which refers to having two empty subclasses of an entity and using RTTI to determine at runtime what the current instance is.  One subclass indicates an instance with a bit "on" and another subclass indicates an instance with the bit "off".  This also implies that there must be some method to "flip" that (implied) bit, since the original algorithm implemented involves setting the referenced bit.

Comment: Casting only changes a reference. I am not sure what the author is talking about there. You can't change an object's class at runtime. I think you're misunderstanding what a cast actually does. Casting doesn't change the type of an object, only the type of a reference.

Comment: Looking at the paper, the method you're trying to implement is actually discussed in [High Performance Dynamic Lock-Free Hash Tables
and List-Based Sets](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/m/michael/spaa-2002.pdf)

Comment: @MarkElliot: I scanned that paper, and I do not see any reference to RTTI or using type identification at runtime to differentiate between whether an element is flagged or not.  I already have an implementation working that uses `AtomicMarkableReference`, but my professor has asked that I attempt to replicate this algorithm as closely as possible.

Comment: @KenP the point is the paper uses CAS operations, not CAS+Marking operations. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thing is, all Java knows at compile-time is that you've declared your `item` as a `Node`. At runtime, however, the JVM knows the actual class of your object. From that moment on, from the Java perspective, **casting is only legal along the inheritance chain**. Even that one might fail if you don't pay enough attention (an object built as a Node cannot be cast as a DeletedNode for example). Since your inherited Node types are sibling classes, the cast along the inheritance chain will fail and will throw the well known ClassCastException.

Comment: So, I could in theory create a "Node" with a "ValidNode" (empty) subclass, and to "twiddle" the bit, I cast that ValidNode to its superclass, and then I could check if ( node instanceof ValidNode ) would tell me if the node had NOT yet been deleted?

Comment: It goes down to the same thing. You're basically saying you want to go up the chain, then down on a different path. No, it doesn't work the way you say it.

Comment: To check if your node is deleted or not, you may want to add a method isDeleted() or something in your base class, then override it in your subclasses. Instead of weird casting you could write something like if (item.isDeleted()) which is much more elegant. Then again, I don't know what your final goal is, so...

Comment: @KenP: casting doesn't change the type of an object. Never. And there's no way to change the type of an object. All you can do is create another object of a different type.

Comment: My final goal is to replicate as closely as possible the algorithm described in this paper so I can compare my (new) algorithm against it.  I have already requested of one of the authors the original code they used, but it was never released for publication, and the original entity (Sun Labs) no longer exists as such.

Comment: Then I'd recommend creating your class hierarchy with polymorphic methods. As (JB Nizet) said, you can't change the type of your object unless you create another one with the type you want.

Answer (score 1):

A cursory read of your referenced [A Lazy Concurrent List-Based Set Algorithm](http://cs.brown.edu/~mph/HellerHLMSS05/2005-OPODIS-Lazy.pdf) actually points to an algorithm description in [High Performance Dynamic Lock-Free Hash Tables
and List-Based Sets](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/m/michael/spaa-2002.pdf).

Notably, the first paper states:

> Achieving the effect of marking a bit in the next pointer is done more efficiently than with `AtomicMarkableReference` by having two trivial (empty) subclasses of each entry object and using RTTI to determine at runtime which subclass the current instance is, where each subclass represents a state of the mark bit.

Heading over to the [`AtomicMarkableReference` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicMarkableReference.html) we see that this class stores a reference and an associated boxed `boolean`.

The second referenced paper shows algorithms using nominal subtypes of `Node` in atomic compare-and-swap operations. Notably there's no casting going on, just some instance swaps.

I could reason that using an [`AtomicReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) might be faster than an `AtomicMarkableReference` because there's less stuff to get and set during CAS operations. Using subclasses might actually be faster, but code would look like:

```
AtomicReference<? extends Node> ref = new AtomicReference<? extends Node>();
Node deletedNode = new DeletedNode();
Node validNode = new ValidNode();
...
ref.compareAndSet(validNode, deletedNode); // or some logic
```

As noted in the comments, there's no way to cast from one subclass to another, you cannot say an "Apple" is a "Banana" even if both are types of "Fruit". You can, however, carry around instances and swap atomic references.